# One of base definitions (elementary set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $a$ is a natural number . I was asked to **define precisely** :$$a+a+a$$  This is my definition:

" That's the cardinality of union of three sets with **same cardinality** , if they are **disjoint** then it would be $3a$ and else it would be less than $3a$ "

Is it enough ?

Comment: What is $a$? Can you write down precisely what the question was?

Comment: @ancientmathematician A natural number.

Comment: Can you say how your book defined $a+a$? or $a+b$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician In our book, a+b is the cardianlity of two disjoint sets with cardinality a and b . But for two sets with same cardinality It doesnt have any definition. And I should say one of book examples proves that c+c=c when c = card R .

Comment: @ancientmathematician After this explanations , is my definition enough?

Comment: If $a$ is a *natural* number, then sum is already defined: $a+a+a=(a+a)+a$

Comment: Seems to me it doesn't make much sense to say that $a+a+a$ can be less than $3a$.

Comment: So as you say all, thats enough to say they are equal  to $3a$ and no need to "less than $3a$" case .

Comment: Maybe you have to correct the text of the question; suppose $A$ is a set with cardinality $a$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

If $A$ is a *set*, see [Cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic):

> If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, addition [of cardinal numbers] is given by their union: $A \cup B$. If the two sets are not already disjoint, then they can be replaced by disjoint sets of the same cardinality, i.e. replace $A$ by $A × \{ 0 \}$ and $B$ by $Y × { 1 }.

Thus:

> > $|A| + |A| := |(A × \{ 0 \})| + |(A × \{ 1 \})|$.

Why this "convoluted" definition? Because we want that, for finite sets, their *cardinality* is exactly the number of elements of the set, i.e, for $A = \{ a,b,c \}$ we want that $|A|=3$ and with $B = \{ d,e,f \}$ we want that $|A+B|=|A|+|B|=6$.

An our definition works, because $A \cup B = \{ a,b,c,d,e,f \}$ and thus $|A \cup B|=6$.

What happen with $|A|+|A|$?

If we ignore the "disjoint" proviso, due to the fact that $A \cup A=A$ we have that $|A \cup A|= |A|=3$ contrary to our expectations: we want to count the elements of two "copies" of set $A$.

In conclusion, we have to avoid conflating the two operations of *sum* of cardinals of sets $+$ with the union of sets $\cup$.

This is why, with sets $A$ and $B$, we write $A \cup B$ but **not** $A+B$.